# bootstrap notify not working

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, angular

I have written a simple example to demonstrate the use of bootstrap notify but its not working.

Below is my code:

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script src="bootstrap-notify.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap-notify.min.js"></script>

    <script>$.notify("Hello World");</script>



</head>

<body>

</body>
```

Comment: Why are you including `bootstrap-notify` twice? Use the [browser console (dev tools)](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit `F12`) and read any errors. “Not working” is not a problem description.

Comment: I already tried browser console, it's not showing any error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your script as below just add ready function it work fine. and also add bootstrap css for look good.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $.notify("Hello World");
    });
</script>
```